# How to use curly braces path name in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell

I used to use paths like this `ls {path1,path2}/*` in Linux but in Windows PowerShell, I got the following error

```
At line:1 char:10
+ ls {path1,path2}/*
+          ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

I tried `dir {path1,path2}/*` instead of `ls {path1,path2}/*` but the same error thrown!!

Comment: Please explain what the given `ls` command does in Linux, and under which Linux shell.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin `ls` is the same as `dir` in windows, list the files and directories under the given path, and it works on any Unix based system under any shell.

Comment: I'm sorry; that far I'd gotten - I should have been clearer: I'm not familiar with the brace convention in Linux; there isn't any such thing under DOS/Windows. That's what I'd like explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the proper cmdlet/alias for the environment you are working in (consider on linux PowerShell Core `ls` refers to the system `ls` not the PoSh gci)

PowerShell allows [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1) `*?`(and ranges`[0-2]`) on multple levels, so this should do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path some\verbose[12]\dir\* -Include *.ext1,*.ext2
```

In case the part of the path differs completely you'll have to supply an array:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path some\this\dir\*,some\that\dir\* -Include *.ext1,*.ext2
```

Comment: This is great. I don't know why after all this time that I didn't know ranges could be used as a wildcard.

Comment: @AdminOfThings They are quite handy, albeit not as versatile as RegEx classes (missing quantifiers, negations etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
ls path1,path2 -recurse
```

Path1 and Path2 will either need to be variables or quoted Strings.

Here is an example

```
PS C:\> ls "c:\temp\test1","c:\temp\test2" -recurse


    Directory: C:\temp\test1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2/14/2019  10:29 AM                test1subdir


    Directory: C:\temp\test1\test1subdir


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/14/2019  10:29 AM             13 test1file.txt


    Directory: C:\temp\test2


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/14/2019  10:30 AM              6 test2file.log
```

I know this may be crazy, but you can create a function that will nearly replicate what you are trying to do:

```
function new-ls {

param([Parameter(Position=0)]
[string]$Path,
[Parameter(Position=1)]
[string[]]$Includes)


$StrMatch = ($Path | sls -pattern "^(.*?){(.*?),(.*?)}(.*?)$" -allmatches).matches.groups.value
$NewPaths = @(($StrMatch[1] + $StrMatch[2] + $StrMatch[4]), ($StrMatch[1] + $StrMatch[3] + $StrMatch[4]))
ls $NewPaths -include $Includes -recurse

}

# Running the code

PS C:\temp> new-ls "c:\temp\{test1,test2}\*"


    Directory: C:\temp\test1\test1subdir


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/14/2019  10:29 AM             13 test1file.txt


    Directory: C:\temp\test2


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/14/2019  10:30 AM              6 test2file.log


PS C:\temp> new-ls "c:\temp\{test1,test2}\*" "*.txt"


    Directory: C:\temp\test1\test1subdir


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/14/2019  10:29 AM             13 test1file.txt

PS C:\temp> new-ls "c:\temp\{test1,test2}\*" "*.txt","*.log"


    Directory: C:\temp\test1\test1subdir


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/14/2019  10:29 AM             13 test1file.txt


    Directory: C:\temp\test2


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/14/2019  10:30 AM              6 test2file.log
```

Comment: Nice this syntax works, but what if paths are verbose like `under/sub/dir/{path1,path2}/*` how to implement path like that?!

Comment: For example, I want to list all `.ext1` and `.ext2` files under directories `some/verbose1/dir` and `some/verbose2/dir`, it'll looks like that in Linux `ls some/{verbose1,verbose2}/dir/*.{ext1,ext2}`

Comment: I do not know of a one-liner that isn't really complicated that can do that in PowerShell. You could make this happen though with multiple lines.